# WCF service interface exchange

Tags: .net, wcf, duplex, duplex-channel

I want to avoid the duplex Chanel in WCF and create callback service on client, pass the client address to server so the server can call the client any time. (maybe different binding etc.)

How can I pass the callback interface to the client? (I still want the server to manage this interface and to avoid put it in seperate DLL. 
Any Ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a duplex binding?

Comment: The built-in mechanism open "service" on the client side. I have no control on this service, binding (automatic save as the main service), lifetime etc. 
If I create "normal" service on client I can send the properties to server and the roles being inverted. 
If the client shut down I can open it. I can use msmq as return channel and more...

Answer (score 0):

Such interface can be passed only in shared assembly.